# setting new class in div

Tags: javascript, html, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

I'm trying to set div's attributes with this script. And i have problem in third line, where I'm trying to get div-s from parent div which id is "loading". but here the problem, it seems like there in variable divs is nothing. why's that?

Script:

```
function  blink() {
    document.getElementById("loading").setAttribute("class","loader");
    var divs = document.getElementById("loading").getElementsByTagName("div");
    alert(divs[0].class);
    for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
        var _id = divs[i].id;
        document.getElementById(divs[i].id).setAttribute("class", "bar");
    }       
}
```

html:

```
<div id="loading" class="loader2">
<a href="#" onClick="blink()">
    <div class="bar_"></div>
    <div class="bar_"></div>
    <div class="bar_"></div></a>
</div>
```

I want to replace divs class: "bar_" to "bar". that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You shouldn't use block-elements `<div>` inside inline-elements `<a>`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- [`class` is a future reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words#In_ECMAScript_5) in JavaScript. Use `className`, not `class`.
- As a general rule, use properties, not `setAttribute`
- There's no need to re-get the `<div>` by ID when you already have them in `divs`!

So:

```
function blink() {
    var loader = document.getElementById("loading");
    loader.className = "loader";
    var divs = loader.getElementsByTagName("div");

    for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].className = "bar";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting a `div` inside an `a` tag is not valid html, which doesn't help. But the main problems are that to read the class attribute you need to use `el.className`. Also, you're trying to read the id attribute for your inner divs when you haven't defined it in the html.